# Multiple reminders plugin has not works on blackberry 10 using cordova

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10

I am looking for a Reminder plugin that works with specifically with Blackberry 10, that is compatible with Phonegap (Cordova). I have seen the old one, but from what I have seen it does not work with the version of Phonegap(Cordova). Does anyone idea of where I can get a plugin that works with Phonegap(Cordova) with example?

Anyone developed an alarm or local notification in Blackberry 10 and PhoneGap(Cordova)? I managed to put it working in Android And iOS but not with Blackberry 10.

I had implemented reminder plugin for IOS and Android below is link http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
it's properly working, but not Working in blackberry 10.

Can you help?